# data-values from checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to get some data-values from checkboxes, as shown below.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-administration="" data-dosage="" data-date="" disabled checked/>
<input type="checkbox" data-administration="" data-dosage="" data-date="" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" data-administration="" data-dosage="" data-date=""/>
```

I only want to get the data from the checked, but not disabled checkboxes, so my selector looks like this:

```
var dosages = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked:not(:disabled)');
```

Seems to work fine, but when I try to get the values like so:

```
for (var index = 0; index < dosages.size(); index++) {
    console.log(dosages[index].data('date'));
  }
```

I get a "data is not a function" error. 
console.log(dosage[index]); returns the elements in this form:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-date="21.10.2014" data-dose="" data-administration="16" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
```

Any clues or maybe suggestions how I could do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bracket-notation to retrieve an object at a given index, you're retrieving the DOM node, not the jQuery object; you need to use `eq()`:

```
dosages.eq(index).data('date')
```

And, honestly, you could do this more easily, while avoiding the `for` loop:

```
dosages.each(function () {
    console.log($(this).data('date'));
});
```

If you wanted to retrieve an array of these values:

```
var dates = dosages.map(function () {
    return $(this).data('date');
 }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this doesn't work is that the elements that are iterable in a jQuery object are the raw dom nodes, not separate jQuery elements. You could use `dosages.eq(index)` to get a jQuery object for each, but there is no need for it.

If you use the raw element, you can access the data attributes via the `element.dataset` object instead of a `element.data()` function, which is a jQuery construct.

Alternatively, using `getAttribute` instead of the data API works about everywhere, even in ancient browsers. No need for jQuery.

```
for (var index = 0; index < dosages.size(); index++) {
    console.log(dosages[index].getAttribute('data-date'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're calling `.data` (a jQuery function) on a DOM element, rather than a jQuery object.

Change

```
dosages[index].data('date')
```

to

```
$(dosages[index]).data('date')
```

**Aside**

The code you've supplied could also be refactored to use jQuery's `each` too (if you wanted):

```
$.each(dosages, function()
{
    console.log($(this).data('date'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that damn $ was exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

you need `.eq()`

```
for (var index = 0; index < dosages.size(); index++) {
   console.log(dosages.eq(index).data('date'));
}
```